# How i can check boolean field in Javascript during the submitting of the form in a Django project

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I want to check the char fields  of my form if they are filled otherwise a msg will displayed, in same way I want to check **2 BooleanField** exist in the same form, if both of them is false a message labeled will be displayed also,

The issue that the first condition it works normally and show me the msg **"Form incomplete. Please, fill out every field!"** but the "second condition(`if(model1 == false && model2 == false )`)) it doesn't give me a result where i want to check both of the BooleanField if they are `false`.
Here is my code:

**javascript code:**

```
  <script language="JavaScript">
    function mySubmitFunction(e) {
      var profession = $("#id_profession").val();
      var taille = $("#id_taille").val();
      var model1 = $('#id_model1').val();
      var model2 = $('#id_model2').val();
      let myVars = [profession, taille]

      if (myVars.includes("") || myVars.includes("Empty")) {
        document.getElementById('submit_label').innerHTML = 'Form incomplete. Please, fill out every field!';
        e.preventDefault();
        someBug();
        return false;
        if(model1 == false && model2 == false ){
          document.getElementById('submit_label2').innerHTML = 'Check one of the model please in Models Section!';
          e.preventDefault();
          someBug();
          return false;
    }
      } 
      else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    </script>
```

**the boolean fields in the template.html:**

```
<span id="a_model1" >{{ form.model1}} </span>
<span id="a_model2" >{{ form.model2}}</span>
```

in **models.py:**

```
model1 = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=" model1")
model2 = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=" model2")
```

so i want to know How i can  check  boolean field in Javascript  during the  submitting of the form using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Before defining decision statement, check the type of the value that is stored in "#a_model1" and #a_model2" fields. If both fields stores there value in string type, you may have to create decision based on that.

If 'a_model1' and 'a_model2' fields are having boolean values with the string type, you can use the below condition.

```
 if('#a_model1' == 'false' && '#a_model2' == 'false' )
```

In javascript, an empty string, 0 will be evaluated to false values. If the user types "false" or "true" in a form field, it will be converted to string while accessing those values in jquery. It would be better, if you specify the type of values those fields will be storing in HTML.

Comment: Hi thanks @B.Anup, I have tried with( if('#a_model1' == 'false' && '#a_model2' == 'false' )) but it doesn't give me any result and as comment am not checking a string , am checking a boolean field (that will be checked or not by the user in the view)